# TYPO3: "section jumper"?

Tags: menu, typo3

I have a very simple page which only has 10 "file links" elements. I need something like a fixed menu (top or right) that allows me to quickly jump back and forth between those "file links" elements (from #10 to #7, back to #10, to #2 ecetera). I probably use the wrong search keywords, such as "section jumper" xD' I hope you know what I mean / am trying to describe.

Comment: Do you already have `id`s on your file links? You can use those to jump to the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a section menu. depending on your TYPO3 version it might be a variant of the general menu CE or it is an own CE.
By default it evaluates the CEs of a page which are enabled for this kind of menu, so be sure that your CEs are enabled (which is default).

Also you can only jump to single CEs. If you have all file links in one CE you only will get one section. Either you have each file link in a single CE or you need special rendering which generates aside from the single file link a special 'file link menu'.

Comment: thank you, I found that content element menu as "section index". it works as you've described. it automatically detects all CE's on the page and lists them with a "jumper-link". however: when I jump to one element, the menu is gone because it's at the top. how can I make that menu accessible all the time?

Comment: either you use CSS/JS to position it static on the screen, or you insert that kind of CE multiple times (be sure to exclude them from the index)

Comment: That first option sounds good since I have experience in CSS/JS coding (but not with typo3). Can you elaborate a little more on this option?

Comment: I think I'm on the right track: I found out that the HTML id of the section index is c205. I guess that is because it is the 205th content element that has been created, so this ID shouldn't change (unless I delete and recreate the menu). So I've added a pure HTML content element with <style> tags where I adress #c205 in order to modify it. Not sure if this is a stupid way to solve my problem though.

Comment: okay got it: from the pure HTML content element I change the styling of the menu content element via #c205{position: fixed; right:5%;}

Comment: depending on your usage: if you only have one page with this construct it is ok. if you have multiple pages you would need to configure multiple IDs (one for each page) and that is a hassle. for multiple pages I would suggest a special (BE-)layout, where you insert the CE in a special column and give this column a special ID you can use for all pages with this layout. You might even inherit the column content and use just one CE (show sections of current(!) page)